# ESP8266 problem as Web server

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, wifi, web-server, esp8266

I asked a previous question about esp8266 that made a lot of things clear for me that esp8266 is very powerful and can be independently used as the webserver now, I have used the following library(https://github.com/sandeepmistry/esp8266-Arduino) to achieve this thing as I found a tutorial(https://learn.adafruit.com/esp8266-temperature-slash-humidity-webserver/code) to help me out.
Now this is the code that was in the tutorial and is working fine

```
/* DHTServer - ESP8266 Webserver with a DHT sensor as an input

   Based on ESP8266Webserver, DHTexample, and BlinkWithoutDelay (thank you)

   Version 1.0  5/3/2014  Version 1.0   Mike Barela for Adafruit Industries
*/
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
#define DHTPIN  2

const char* ssid     = "--MYRouterID";
const char* password = "--MYRouterPassword";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

// Initialize DHT sensor 
// NOTE: For working with a faster than ATmega328p 16 MHz Arduino chip, like an ESP8266,
// you need to increase the threshold for cycle counts considered a 1 or 0.
// You can do this by passing a 3rd parameter for this threshold.  It's a bit
// of fiddling to find the right value, but in general the faster the CPU the
// higher the value.  The default for a 16mhz AVR is a value of 6.  For an
// Arduino Due that runs at 84mhz a value of 30 works.
// This is for the ESP8266 processor on ESP-01 
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE, 11); // 11 works fine for ESP8266

float humidity, temp_f;  // Values read from sensor
String webString="";     // String to display
// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last temp was read
const long interval = 2000;              // interval at which to read sensor

void handle_root() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello from the weather esp8266, read from /temp or /humidity");
  delay(100);
}

void setup(void)
{
  // You can open the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor window to see what the code is doing
  Serial.begin(115200);  // Serial connection from ESP-01 via 3.3v console cable
  dht.begin();           // initialize temperature sensor

  // Connect to WiFi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("\n\r \n\rWorking to connect");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("DHT Weather Reading Server");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handle_root);

  server.on("/temp", [](){  // if you add this subdirectory to your webserver call, you get text below :)
    gettemperature();       // read sensor
    webString="Temperature: "+String((int)temp_f)+" F";   // Arduino has a hard time with float to string
    server.send(200, "text/plain", webString);            // send to someones browser when asked
  });

  server.on("/humidity", [](){  // if you add this subdirectory to your webserver call, you get text below :)
    gettemperature();           // read sensor
    webString="Humidity: "+String((int)humidity)+"%";
    server.send(200, "text/plain", webString);               // send to someones browser when asked
  });

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void)
{
  server.handleClient();
} 

void gettemperature() {
  // Wait at least 2 seconds seconds between measurements.
  // if the difference between the current time and last time you read
  // the sensor is bigger than the interval you set, read the sensor
  // Works better than delay for things happening elsewhere also
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you read the sensor 
    previousMillis = currentMillis;   

    // Reading temperature for humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
    // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (it's a very slow sensor)
    humidity = dht.readHumidity();          // Read humidity (percent)
    temp_f = dht.readTemperature(true);     // Read temperature as Fahrenheit
    // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
    if (isnan(humidity) || isnan(temp_f)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Now this is my modification of code(of esp8266) as I am willing to communicate it over serial with my arduino which will further send data to the esp8266 when it requests using the attached sensor to the batteries(I am making a solar related project).

Its only a basic code but the problem is that it compiles and runs ok but I am only able to access the web page once and that is also only the root. The other links do not open up or when I try to even reload the web page root it stuck and browser says error timed out

Here is code

```
void handle_root() {
  //server.send(208, "text/plain", "<h1>Hello from the weather esp8266, read from /temp or /humidity</h1>");
  String sendx = "<h1>This Page Shows the Basic Info</h1>";
//  Serial.write("MP");
//  delay(20);

//  while(Serial.available()>0)
 // {
  //  rec = Serial.readString();
  //}
  rec = "TESt";
  if(rec[0] == AllMain)
  {
     sendx += "<h2>Running on Main Power Now</h2>";
     sendx += "<p>" + rec + "</p>";
  }
  else if(rec[0] == HouseMain)
  {
    sendx += "<h2>Home on Main Power</h2>"; 
    sendx += "<p>" + rec + "</p>";
    sendx += "<a href =\"/thos\">Turn on Hospital Main</a>";
  }
  else if(rec[0]==HospitalMain)
  {
    sendx += "<h2>Hospital on Main Power</h2>"; 
    sendx += "<p>" + rec + "</p>";
    sendx += "<a href =\"/thm\">Turn on House Main</a>";
  }
  else
  {
    sendx += "<p>" + rec + "</p>";
    sendx += "<h4><a href =\"/thm\">Turn on House Main</a></h4>";
    sendx += "<h4><a href =\"/thos\">Turn on Hospital Main</a></h4>";
  }
// sendx +=  "<a href =\""+".."+"/temp\">Temp</a>";


    server.send(200,"text/html",sendx);
  delay(100);
}
void thm()
{
 // if(Serial.available())
  {
//    Serial.println("thm");
    String sendx = "signal sent... go back to previous page to verify";
  //  sendx += "<a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">Go Back</a>";
    server.send(200,"text/html",sendx);
    delay(100);
  }
}
void thos()
{
 // if(Serial.available())
  {
//    Serial.println("thos");
    String sendx = "signal sent... go back to previous page to verify";
 //   sendx += "<a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">Go Back</a>";
    server.send(200,"text/html",sendx);
    delay(100);
  }
}
void setup(void)
{
  // You can open the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor window to see what the code is doing
  Serial.begin(115200);  // Serial connection from ESP-01 via 3.3v console cable

  // Connect to WiFi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if(debug)
    Serial.print("\n\r \n\rWorking to connect");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    if(debug)
      Serial.print(".");
  }
  if(debug)
  {
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("DHT Weather Reading Server");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }
  if (mdns.begin("esp8266", WiFi.localIP())) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handle_root);

 server.on("/thm", thm);
 /*server.on("/thm", [](){  ===== I have tried this inline as well no luck ====
   Serial.println("thos");
    String sendx = "signal sent... go back to previous page to verify";
    server.sendContent(sendx);
 });*/
  server.on("/thos",thos);

  server.begin();
  if(debug)
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void)
{

  server.handleClient();
}
```

Now please I would also appreciate your help for the commented portion of my code dealing with serial communication in function `handle_root` but it would be more than enough if you can point out my misconception or error or point me in right direction